# Heatmap with 2 numerical variables and 1 categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am facing an issue, which I think it’s mainly related to coding, and I would appreciate some help please. 
I would need to perform a data visualization in python framework (Jupyter Notebook), with 3 variables: 2 of them are numerical (`num_var1` and `num_var2`) and one categorical (`cat_var`). 
I would like to use `num_var1` as a categorical one by binning it.

I thought that I could use a heatmap to visualize these 3 variables:

- `num_var1` in the columns, by binning it
- `cat_var` in the rows
- `num_var2` as the color

I thought that to bin a numerical variable I could use the `pd.cut()` function and so I have written the following code:

```
cat_means = df.groupby([pd.cut(df.num_var1, 10), 'cat_var']).mean()['num_var2'] 
cat_means = cat_means.reset_index(name = 'num_var2_avg') 
cat_means = cat_means.pivot(index = 'cat_var', columns = pd.cut(df.num_var1, 10), values = 'num_var2_avg') 
seaborn.heatmap(cat_means, annot = True, fmt = '.3f', cbar_kws = {'label' : 'mean(num_var2)'});
```

Instead of the expected heatmap, the output is the following error:

```
KeyError: "[Interval(-0.01, 1.001, closed='right')\n Interval(-0.01, 1.001, closed='right')\n Interval(-0.01, 1.001, closed='right') ...\n Interval(-0.01, 1.001, closed='right')\n Interval(-0.01, 1.001, closed='right')\n Interval(-0.01, 1.001, closed='right')] not in index"
```

Could anyone help me on this please?

Many thanks,

Federico

Comment: In `.pivot` `columns` must be the name of a dataframe column.

Comment: Thanks ImportanceOfBeingErnest for your help. I kind of fixed the issue by creating an additional column with discrete data based on 'num_var1' and then used that coulmn for the pivot. I can't believe there is no way of doing this using the original column though..

Comment: Well, feel free to not believe it then.

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest please don't get me wrong, I did appreciate your help a lot :) I was just a bit surprised that it couldn't be done otherwise if not by creating another column..I still have a lot to learn :)